# How to use panning with WebKitGTK?

Tags: webkit, gtk, panning

I want to use WebKitGTK on a touchscreen device. Since operating scroll bars on such a device is too cumbersome I would like to have some panning support. Since WebKit is used on quite a number of mobile devices which all support panning I hope that WebKit/WebKitGTK has some support for it.

So the question is how to activate it?

WebKitGTK does not have an API for activating it. CSS also does not seem to be suitable for switching it on.

Version of WebKitGTK to be used is 1.11.5 since the target architecture has no compiler with full C++11 support but is restricted to gcc-4.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using WebKit 1.x, you should put the `WebKitWebView` in a `GtkScrolledWindow`. If you have a new enough version of GTK, then the scrolled window should support vertical and horizontal scrolling on mobile devices.

Comment: I already have that. It adds  scrollbars to the window and I can scroll using the scrollbars. But I want to scroll by touching the middle of the page and dragging with the finger instead of having to hit the tiny scroll bars. This is what I mean as panning.

Comment: In that case I would suggest to use [`GtkGesture`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkGesture.html) and adjust the scroll bars when detecting such a gesture.